# Filter Customers by a custom field

Tags: magento, filtering

I using magento 1.6.1

I have only mobile number and name of the customers. I need to load those customers.

How it is possible to select those customers in magento.

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked. If you need a customer collection, just use `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');` as a starting point and then you can filter as needed; see http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/using_collections_in_magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code helps me to filter the customers.

```
$customers  = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $firstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$customers    = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $firstName)`

The above code will only load the collection.

To get customer details by firstname, we need to loop through customer collection object and then get customer id. Finally just load the individual customer object as below

```
$model = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');

$customerCollection = $model->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', array('like' => $variableFirstName));

foreach($customerCollection as $customerObject) 
{       
    $customer = $model->load($customerObject->getId());
    echo '<b>'.$customer->getFirstname() . $customer->getLastname().'</b><br/>';
}
```

In case, if we want to filter by lastname, just change to

```
->addAttributeToFilter('lastname', array('like' => $variableLastName))
```